# How can I print multiple rows of multiple matrixes in C?

Tags: c, string, matrix, vector

I need to receive N numbers of names, citys and abiliitys, and then print then.

This is what I have so far, and I don't know why it is not working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int N, i, j;
  scanf("%d %d", &N);
  char name[i][10];
  char city[i][100];
  int abiliity[i][100];

  for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    scanf("%s %s %d", name[i], city[i], &abiliity[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
      printf("%c %c %d\n", name[i][j], city[i][j], abiliity[i][j]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char name[i][10];` Your array declarations have undefined behaviour because they use an uninitialised variable, `i`. Change that to use `N` instead.

Comment: `for(j=0;j<1000;j++){` That makes no sense. Why would you use `1000` when your arrays clearly do not have that many characters in them? So that also results in Undefined Behaviour as it overflows the buffers. And it also doesn't make sense to print one character from each array - the result will be interleaved characters from each string. Use `%s` to print the whole string instead.

Comment: Please explain your reasoning for  `char name[i][10];` and `for(j=0;j<1000;j++)`. I am with kaylums observations on that, but I want to know the cause for that weirdness. If you describe your reasoning we might be able to pinpoint the source of your problems. Otherwise the question gives an impression of showing randomly cobbled code fragments and asking to "fix" something which was never really written on a foundation of understanding. I would tend to close the question as not reproducable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int N, i;
    printf("N:");
    scanf("%d", &N); //you only need one %d
    char name[N][10]; //put here N instead of i
    char city[N][100]; //put here N instead of i
    int ability[N]; //put here N instead of i. It's not a string, so you don't need a 2D array

    printf("type %d times the name, city and ability\n", N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        scanf("%s %s %d", name[i], city[i], &ability[i]);

    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        //you don't need the second for loop if you use %s
        printf("%s %s %d\n", name[i], city[i], ability[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```